# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string for SOAP request

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

When I run the following script, I get an "**Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string for SOAP request**" error on the `$client->LatLonListZipCode($args)` line and I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

```
<?php
$contextOptions = array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer'   => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
            ),
            'http' => array(
                'timeout' => 5 //seconds
            )
 );

//create stream context
$stream_context = stream_context_create($contextOptions);

//create client instance (over HTTPS)
$client = new SoapClient('http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/wsdl/ndfdXML.wsdl', array(
            'cache_wsdl'  => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
            'exceptions' => 1,
            'trace' => 1,
            'stream_context' => $stream_context,
            'soap_version'=> SOAP_1_2,
            'connection_timeout' => 5 //seconds
));//SoapClient

$args = new stdClass();
$args->zipCodeList = '10001';

$z = $client->LatLonListZipCode($args);
```

Comment: `LatLonListZipCode` expects a string as parameter, while you are passing `stdClass`. There is nothing to add unless you will share the knowledge about the expected `LatLonListZipCode` parameters list. `SoapClient` [operates string instances](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php).

Comment: @mudasobwa - I don't pretend to be a SOAP expert but it seems to me that the WSDL is expecting the string to be passed to it as a parameter named zipCodeList. If I do `$client->LatLonListZipCode('10001')` how would it know what the parameter name was? None-the-less, I tried it and got a `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Client] Operation '' is not defined in the WSDL for this service` error

Comment: Would you mind to try with `$client->__soapCall('LatLonListZipCode', array('zipCodeList' => array('10001')))` [`__soapCall`](http://php.net/manual/de/soapclient.soapcall.php) always just worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Exception cause

First of all - this service is using **SOAP 1.1** *not* **SOAP 1.2**. Change your `$client` specification to:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/wsdl/ndfdXML.wsdl', array(
            'cache_wsdl'  => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
            'exceptions' => 1,
            'trace' => 1,
            'stream_context' => $stream_context,
            'soap_version'=> SOAP_1_1,//<-- note change here
            'connection_timeout' => 5 //seconds
));//SoapClient
```

## Service Definition

As it is stated in your [WSDL service specification](http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLserver.php?wsdl), you can find that `LatLonListZipCode` function is defined as:

```
<operation name="LatLonListZipCode">
    <documentation>Returns a list of latitude and longitude pairs with each pair corresponding to an input zip code.</documentation>
    <input  message="tns:LatLonListZipCodeRequest"/>
    <output message="tns:LatLonListZipCodeResponse"/>
</operation>
```

and expected parameters are defined as:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="zipCodeListType">
    <xsd:restriction base='xsd:string'>
        <xsd:pattern value="\d{5}(\-\d{4})?( \d{5}(\-\d{4})?)*" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

## Proper call

So we know, that server demands only one `string` parameter named `zipCodeList`. Now we can deduct that your code should be like this:

```
$args = array("zipCodeList"=>'10001');
try {
$z = $client->LatLonListZipCode($args);
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    echo $e->faultcode;
}
```

Note that i'm catching `SoapFault` exception. It will help you to understand server-side errors. Read more about it in [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/pl/soapfault.soapfault.php).

Comment: That worked. Although I think it is a little silly. Seems like PHP could have auto-converted StdClass to an array ala `$args = (array) $args`. Also, catching Exceptions is certainly best practice, but in a quick proof of concept on an environment where errors are being displayed it is unnecessary. An uncaught Exception triggers a fatal error and in the environment I just described is displayed. None-the-less, your answer did get it working, so I'll award the bounty to you in 10h (that's how much longer I have to wait before awarding it)

Comment: I agree with you - it **IS** silly. You can even found in [PHP docs comments](http://php.net/manual/pl/soapclient.soapcall.php#78707) how people are overcoming this ;)